# Geany compiler , c programming, Ubuntu 14.04, can't show program output

Tags: compiling, geany

I wrote a simple program to print "hello world".
The compiler shows a message "Compilation finished successfully".
But the out put of the program, I can't see anywhere.

As using codeblocks a new terminal comes out with the program output.
How can I see the program output using geany compiler.

Comment: @Sudheer You may want to view this question - http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11522/how-to-tell-an-editor-they-are-doing-something-consistently-wrong while you seem to be trying to help, there are some "grammar" issues with your edits, also please note that all usage of single "i"'s are capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your "hello world" program in Geany.
2. From the Geany menu select *Build* -> *Build*. A new executable file will be created in the same directory as your source code.
3. From the Geany menu select *Build* -> *Execute*. A new window with the title **Terminal** will appear with the "hello world" program output.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice about the icon "run or view the current file". Now its working.